# Como recuperar o `mysqli->insert_id` de dentro desta função, além do retorno da query?

Tags: php, mysql, orientação-a-objetos, mysqli

```
public function executar($sql){

    $con = new conexao();
    $con->abrir();
    $re = $con->mysqli->query($sql);

    // Preciso retornar esta informação tambem:
    $last_id = $con->mysqli->insert_id;

    $con->fechar();
    return $re;
}

function inserir($tabela,$dados){

    $arrCampo = array_keys($dados);
    $arrValores = array_values($dados);
    $numCampos = count($arrCampo);
    $numValores = count($arrValores);
    if($numCampos == $numValores){
        $SQL = "INSERT INTO " .$tabela." (";
        foreach($arrCampo as $campo){
            $SQL .= "$campo, ";
        }
        $SQL = substr_replace($SQL, ")", -2, 1);
        $SQL .= "VALUES (";
        foreach($arrValores as $valores){
            $SQL .= "'".$valores."', ";
        }
        $SQL = substr_replace($SQL, ")", -2, 1);
    }else{
        echo "Erro ao verificar campos";
    }
    $this->executar($SQL);

}
```

Estou usando os seguintes códigos, e preciso retornar o ID da ultima inserção no banco.

```
$dados_cliente = array(
    'cliente_nome'=>$cliente_nome,
    'cliente_email'=>$cliente_email,
    'cliente_celular'=>$cliente_celular,
    'cliente_tipo'=>$cliente_tipo,
    'cliente_documento'=>$cliente_documento
);

$comando->inserir('clientes',$dados_cliente);
```

Que é enviado desta forma. Só que após executar o comando `$comando->inserir('clientes',$dados_cliente);` não consigo pegar o valor da última inserção do banco.

Comment: Select Max (coluna)+1 from tabela

Comment: @WillianCoqueiro o problema dessa sua solução é que nem sempre o ID vai ser o MAX+1. Se registros do final da lista de IDS forem deletados, a autonumeração não vai reaproveitar os números, mas o MAX sim, o que pode ser indesejado.

Comment: @Bacco Sim. Se tiver usando auto increment. Geralmente não uso esta função. Mais caso ele use após o insert somente MAX consegue os valores corretos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considerando que você tem a estrutura apresentada dentro de uma classe:

```
public function executar($sql)
{

    $con = new conexao();
    $con->abrir();

    $re = $con->mysqli->query($sql);

    // Preciso retornar esta informação tambem:
    $last_id = $con->mysqli->insert_id;

    $con->fechar();

    return $re;

}

public function inserir($tabela,$dados)
{

    $arrCampo   = array_keys($dados);
    $arrValores = array_values($dados);
    $numCampos  = count($arrCampo);
    $numValores = count($arrValores);

    if($numCampos == $numValores) {

        $SQL = "INSERT INTO " .$tabela." (";
        foreach($arrCampo as $campo){
            $SQL .= "$campo, ";
        }

        $SQL = substr_replace($SQL, ")", -2, 1);

        $SQL .= "VALUES (";
        foreach($arrValores as $valores){
            $SQL .= "'".$valores."', ";
        }

        $SQL = substr_replace($SQL, ")", -2, 1);

    }else{

        echo "Erro ao verificar campos";

    }

    $this->executar($SQL);

}
```

> Considerei que o método `inserir` também pertence a mesma classe, visto que há a utilização de `$this` em seu corpo.

Você pode definir uma propriedade da classe chamada `last_id` e atualizar seu valor dentro do método `executar`:

```
public function executar($sql)
{

    $con = new conexao();
    $con->abrir();

    $re = $con->mysqli->query($sql);

    // A propriedade é atualizada aqui:
    $this->last_id = $con->mysqli->insert_id;

    $con->fechar();

    return $re;

}
```

Desta forma, ela ficará acessível em toda classe. Portanto, no método `inserir` você pode retornar o valor desta propriedade.

```
public function inserir($tabela,$dados)
{

    $arrCampo   = array_keys($dados);
    $arrValores = array_values($dados);
    $numCampos  = count($arrCampo);
    $numValores = count($arrValores);

    if($numCampos == $numValores) {

        $SQL = "INSERT INTO " .$tabela." (";
        foreach($arrCampo as $campo){
            $SQL .= "$campo, ";
        }

        $SQL = substr_replace($SQL, ")", -2, 1);

        $SQL .= "VALUES (";
        foreach($arrValores as $valores){
            $SQL .= "'".$valores."', ";
        }

        $SQL = substr_replace($SQL, ")", -2, 1);

    }else{

        echo "Erro ao verificar campos";

    }

    $this->executar($SQL);

    return $this->last_id;

}
```

Assim, ao invocar o método. você terá acesso ao id do registro adicionado.

```
$dados_cliente = array(
    'cliente_nome'=>$cliente_nome,
    'cliente_email'=>$cliente_email,
    'cliente_celular'=>$cliente_celular,
    'cliente_tipo'=>$cliente_tipo,
    'cliente_documento'=>$cliente_documento
);

$last_id = $comando->inserir('clientes',$dados_cliente);

echo "ID do registro adicionado " . $last_id;
```

Conforme documentação oficial da propriedade [`insert_id`](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli.insert-id.php):

> **Atenção!**  Se a última consulta não foi um INSERT ou UPDATE ou se a tabela modificada não tem uma coluna com o atributo AUTO_INCREMENT, esta função irá retornar zero.

Comment: +1, aproveitando a classe fica limpo o código

Comment: Limpo e simples, era isso mesmo que estava precisando, estou em transição do `mysql` para `mysqli` e ainda tem algumas diferenças que estou tendo dificuldades.

Comment: Por favor, clique em aceitar a resposta para sinalizar o tópico como concluído.

Comment: 2019 e eu aqui novamente com essa questão. Existe alguma forma de fazer sem usar o $this?

Comment: @HelisonSantos Muitas formas, mas provavelmente isso é assunto para outra pergunta. Ou entra no [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11910/estouro-de-pilha) para discutir melhor.

Comment: A melhor maneira é sem o OOP, assim fica sem $this tambem. Só defende OOP em PHP quem não entende de no mínimo uma das duas coisas (geralmente as duas).

Answer (score 0):

Altere o retorno do seu método para retornar um array.

```
public function executar($sql){

    $con = new conexao();
    $con->abrir();
    $re = $con->mysqli->query($sql);

    // Preciso retornar esta informação tambem:
    $last_id = $con->mysqli->insert_id;

    $con->fechar();
    return array($re, $last_id);
}
```

Depois pode recuperar os dados para uma lista, ou tratar o array da maneira que preferir.

```
list ($operationResult, $lastInsertedValue) = $comando->inserir('clientes',$dados_cliente);
```

Comment: Só cuidado que o método `inserir` não está, da maneira apresentada, retornando o resultado do método `executar`. Ao fazer isso implicaria em alterar o método `inserir` colocando `return $this->executar($SQL);`. Outro porém é que se o método `executar` for invocado por outros métodos, como `atualizar`, `remover`, implicaria em fazer esta alteração em todos eles.

Comment: Melhor seria neste caso usar um parâmetro por referência, executar($sql, &$last_id) assim não mexeria no que já existe, bastaria usar o parâmetro nas funções novas só quando precisar do ID. Mas é válido como solução bem alternativa. Para o caso em concreto, com classe, a solução do Woss é mais limpa, mas é bom mostrar mais de um jeito de fazer.